# Generic method with extend in java

Tags: java, generics, netbeans

I have the class TestClass with a generic method. But when i run the 
method1 with those arguments it executes fine. 
Am i missing something? Should method1 throw exception because object does not extend Integer?

```
 TestClass i = new TestClass();
 i.method1(new Object(), new Integer(2));


  public class TestClass {

        protected final int testClassvar1=2;

        public <E,T extends E> void method1(T t,E e) {
        System.out.println(e.getClass()); 
       }
   }
```

Comment: Still puzzling over this but in the meantime [this might help you](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: It seems like the only way to do this was to define `TestClass<E>` and then in the type signature of the method put `<T extends E>` only, though I still have absolutely no idea why your code doesn't cause the compiler to die...

Comment: [This concerns me](https://tio.run/##dY4/a8MwFMRn@1McmSRwDE229M9SNHTolAyFUIIqv6pOFNlYz2lL8VePasedTDM9uPvd3dvrk55XNfl9cYixbt9caWCcDgHPuvT4SZM/MbDm/pyqssCxt8Sam9Lb7St0Y4McyGSI5EyBhadPjICY3SyWM5lhkJ48k6VGLKS8TZMunbbfqQwb0BeTLwLUwzh3adyAMyjQuLT@DkzHvGo5r/sVdl5wbokfh9fFpf0/hqaMAu9wD6Ek@EqGd/KqM6nr0i7Gs3l32oY4f3E9tmq9@SBzoOIX)

Comment: you are not giving the information for the generics. use `i.<Object, Integer>method1()` otherwise it will assume <Object, Object>

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo OH smart I get it now. Yay I learned something new today as well, turns out. :D

Comment: Can you please explain a little more @SungJinSteveYoo ...I was unable to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enforce the constraint T extends E at compile time, when you call the method you need to specify the types that will replace the parameterized types.  Otherwise, both types are assumed to be Object.

```
i.<Object,Integer>method1(new Object(), new Integer(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not set specific type when call generic method, so the compiler understands it as `i.<Object, Object> method1(new Object(), new Integer(2));`.

Comment: Oracle tutorial generics do not show this method.How we supposed to know this? Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

`method1` will always be able to take two arguments of any reference type, because `T` and `E` can be chosen to be `Object`, and any reference type is a subtype of `Object`. So `method1` might as well be declared as `public void method1(Object t, Object e)`; it would make no difference. The way it is declared, there is nothing that `method1` can do with either of its parameters except the things that can be done with `Object` anyway, since the type variables are not bounded (so Java wouldn't let the programmer do anything with it beyond what can be done with `Object`). (Here, the only thing the method does is call `.toString()` on `e`, which is something that is provided by `Object`.) So there is no reason for any restriction beyond that they are both `Object`.